# While scraping getting error instance method has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I couldn't understand I am getting this error-> instance method has no attribute getitem.
I am just trying to scrape this site to extract the department names.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from amazon.items import AmazonItem

class delhiveryspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.amazon.in"]


    def parse(self,response):
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="nav_browse_flyout"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = AmazonItem()
            item['main_title'] = site.xpath('.//li[@id="nav_cat_0"]/text()').extract[0]
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `extract()` and then get the first item:

```
item['main_title'] = site.xpath('.//li[@id="nav_cat_0"]/text()').extract()[0]
#                                                                  HERE ^
```

If you want to have a separate category for each item, iterate over them:

```
for title in site.xpath('.//li[starts-with(@id, "nav_cat_")]/text()').extract():
    item = AmazonItem()
    item['main_title'] = title
    items.append(item)
```

Comment: hey can you tell me why it is extracting only one list,why all the categories are not extracted??

Comment: when i remove [0] after extract then I am able to get the list but not when using it why?

Comment: @NikhilParmar `.//li[@id="nav_cat_0"]/text()` matches multiple categories, then you are using the `[0]` syntax, you are getting only the first category out of the list..

Comment: but they are coming in one field I want to separate them and get to extract all the field individually and their respective subfields

Comment: @NikhilParmar if I understand you correctly, you want to have a separate item for every category/title - please see the updated answer. Hope this is what you are asking about.

Comment: see amazon.in they have all the categories,what I want is to extract all the categories to come in separate field in the excel sheet.By your code I am still getting only the first

Comment: @NikhilParmar I see what you mean! Updated the xpath expression used inside the selector. Check it out.

Comment: thankyou so much .One more thing can you tell me where I can directly contact in problem plz??

Comment: @NikhilParmar easier is to just ask here on SO - I usually track the `Scrapy` tag questions. Glad it helped.

Comment: can you check my this question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176779/scrapy-isnt-working-right-in-extracting-the-title