# scrapy isn't working right in extracting the title

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, text-extraction

[image]In this code I want to scrape title,subtitle and data inside the links but having issues on pages beyond 1 and 2 as getting only 1 item scraped.I want to extract only those entries having title as delhivery only

```
       import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from delhivery.items import DelhiveryItem




class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "delh"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=2"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = DelhiveryItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/span[@style="background-color:yellow"]/text()').extract()[0]
            #item['title'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a[text() = "%s Delivery Courier %s"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['subtitle'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/b[1]/text()').extract()[0]


            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item['username'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]/a[2]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                     meta={'item': item},
                                     callback=self.anchor_page)

            items.append(item)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//td[@style="padding-bottom:15px"]/div/text()').extract()[0]


        yield old_item
```

Comment: What is your desired output? How is it different from what you have currently? Thanks.

Comment: When I run it I get 'item_scraped_count': 17 , so it gets more than one item, what exactly do you need the output to be?

Comment: there is a title named Delhivery,I only need to scrape those links only 1st,@Vanddel the 17 items you are getting when I have .extract(),if I do it .extract()[0] then only 1 item will be scraped

Comment: See for page=1 and page=2 code work fines and extract data,but for page=3 and page=11,the code doesn't work properly when extracting the title along with the other items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the item['title'] to this:

```
item['title'] = ''.join(site.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]//span[text() = "Delhivery"]/parent::*//text()').extract()[0])
```

Also edit sites to this to extract the required links only (ones with Delhivery in it)

```
sites = response.xpath('//table//span[text()="Delhivery"]/ancestor::div')
```

EDIT:
so I understand now that you need to add a pagination rule to your code.
it should be something like this:
You just need to add your imports and write the new xpaths from **the item's link itself, such as [this one](http://www.consumercomplaints.in/complaints/delhivery-last-mile-courier-service-poor-delivery-service-c772900.html#c1880509)**

```
class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "delh"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery"]

    rules = (
        # Extracting pages, allowing only links with page=number to be extracted 
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagelinks"]', ), allow=('page=\d+', ),unique=True),follow=True),

         # Extract links of items on each page the spider gets from the first rule
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//td[@class="complaint"]', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = DelhiveryItem()
        #populate item object here the same way you did, this function will be called for each item link.
        #This meand that you'll be extracting data from pages like this one : 
        #http://www.consumercomplaints.in/complaints/delhivery-last-mile-courier-service-poor-delivery-service-c772900.html#c1880509
        item['title'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
        item['subtitle'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
        item['date'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0].strip()
        item['username'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
        item['link'] = response.url
        item['data'] = response.xpath('<write xpath>').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Also I suggest when you write an xpath, that you don't use any styling parameters, try to use @class or @id, only use @width, @style or any styling params if it's the only way.

Comment: thankyou,there is serious issue on the website in regard to the coding I am unable to extract the data

Comment: not exactly-see you are correcting every title to bel delhivery courier I dont want that I want to filter out the other title and their review

Comment: can you bring me to a chat I dont have enough reputation,i will tell you in detail

Comment: I understand that you need the links that contains "delhivery" in their title.
so the sites xpath should get you the links with delhivery on it. and the item['title'] xpath should get you the whole title.

Comment: If this is not what you need, please give me an example of the data you need it to be extracted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69757/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-vanddel).

Comment: in your last code you sent me on chat you have to edit the first rule to be like this: 
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagelinks"]', ), allow=('page=\d+', ),unique=True),follow=True, callback='parse_item'), 
and delete the second rule

Comment: I did that @vanddel but it still ain't working not extracting data only crawling through the links

Comment: could you add the edited code to the question?, because I did that and it's working correctly.